# std::remove_all_extents source code excessiveness: why need 3 declarations while 2 is enough

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

When I take a look at sources

```
template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS remove_all_extents
    {typedef _Tp type;};
template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS remove_all_extents<_Tp[]>
    {typedef typename remove_all_extents<_Tp>::type type;};
template <class _Tp, size_t _Np> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS remove_all_extents<_Tp[_Np]>
    {typedef typename remove_all_extents<_Tp>::type type;};
```

I conclude that only first and last declaration is required to make this recursive template work.
Why middle definition is needed?

I tryed to make same functionality with just 2 declarations and it works

Comment: Try compiling `remove_all_extents_t<char[]>` with and without the second explicit specialization. Unbounded arrays were the C type erasure premitives for arrays. They are also used in varaible sized structures, but C++ gives better alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That middle template will help to remove the extent from an array type of unknown bound. Here `T` is `char[]` and the program would not compile without the middle template:

Example:

```cpp
template <template <class...> class C, class T>
void foo(C<T>&) {
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<typename std::remove_all_extents<T>::type, char>::value, "");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> example(new char[1024]);

    foo(example); // passes the assertion, but not without the middle template
}
```